# Spring Test NoMethod Error

Tags: java, spring, testing

I'm using spring to run my test and got weird error which block me for a while.

Writer and Parser are classes with no attributes and only using default constructors.

AbstractTestCaseUnit.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:spring-configuration/unit-test-config.xml" })
public abstract class AbstractTestCaseUnit {

    @Resource(name = "Parser")
    private DataParser Parser;;

    @Resource(name = "Writer")
    private DataWriter Writer;

    public DataParser getMessageParser() {
        return Parser;
    }

    public DataWriter getDataWriter() {
        return Writer;
    }
}
```

DataParseTest.java

```
public class DataParserTest extends AbstractTestCaseUnit {

    @Test
    public void testParseMessageHappyCase() {...}


}
```

unit-test-config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">


        <import resource="unit-test/environment.xml" />

        <bean id="Parser"
            class="com.datatype.DataParser" />

        <bean id="Writer"
            class="com.datatype.DataWriter" />
```

Error:

```
 [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.013 sec
    [junit] 
    [junit] Testcase: initializationError took 0.003 sec
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    [junit] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.resolveContextLoader(ContextLoaderUtils.java:87)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.buildMergedContextConfiguration(ContextLoaderUtils.java:298)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.<init>(TestContext.java:100)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:117)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:119)
    [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:108)
    [junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    [junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    [junit]
```

Comment: You seem to be using incompatible versions of the Spring libraries.

Comment: Sotirios, can you provide more details? How do you know that?

Comment: A `NoSuchMethodError` indicates that a method doesn't exist at runtime. That means that the corresponding code was compiled when the method did exist, but, at runtime, you've providing a version where it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are mixing different (incompatible) versions of Spring components. Check your classpath.

If you are using a project management tool like Maven or Gradle, ensure that the dependencies of your project do not contain Spring artifacts, otherwise they will be picked up by the transitive dependency mechanism.

If using an IDE like Eclipse and Maven, you can open your pom.xml with the POM Editor and check in the *Dependency Hierarchy* tab the resolved dependencies. You can then exclude the offending (often older) dependency.